# Manipulate: variable localization inside nested `Control`

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, localization

Below is a piece of my code I have trouble with:

```
Clear[z1hyp, claim, μ0]
z1hyp[] := Manipulate[claim,
  Control@{{μ0, 0, 
     Control@{{claim, "=", 
        "Claim: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(μ\), \(0\)]\)"}, {"=", 
        "≠", "≥", "≤", "<", ">"}, 
       ControlType -> PopupMenu}}},
  {{xbar, 0, "Sample Mean, \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(-\)]\)"}, 
   InputField},
  {{σ, 1, "Population Std., σ"}, InputField},
  {{n, 10, "Sample Size, n"}, InputField},
  {{α, 0.05, "Alpha, α"}, InputField},
  LocalizeVariables -> True]
```

The nested `Control`s doesn't seem to localize the variable name `claim`.

In general, `Manipulate[{var1, var2},  Control@{{var1, init1, Control@{{var2, init2, "lbl"}}}}]` doesn't localize `var2`. `LocalizeVariables` and `DynamicModule` don't seem to help here.

My question is, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dynamic` on the variable to be localized in a `DynamicModule`:

```
Clear[z1hyp, claim, \[Mu]0];
z1hyp[] := DynamicModule[{claim}, Manipulate[claim,
   {{\[Mu]0, 0,
     Dynamic@Control[{
        {claim, "=", "Claim: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(0\)]\)"},
        {"=", "\[NotEqual]", "\[GreaterEqual]", "\[LessEqual]", "<", 
         ">"},
        ControlType -> PopupMenu
     }]
    }, InputField},
   {{xbar, 0, "Sample Mean, \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(-\)]\)"}, 
    InputField},
   {{\[Sigma], 1, "Population Std., \[Sigma]"}, InputField},
   {{n, 10, "Sample Size, n"}, InputField},
   {{\[Alpha], 0.05, "Alpha, \[Alpha]"}, InputField}]];

{Dynamic[claim], z1hyp[]}
```

This happens because the `Manipulate` outside only localizes what you give it as firsts of its arguments, which is `var1`, whereas `var2` appears as part of the *label* of `var1`, so it's impossible for `Manipulate` to know that you also want `var2` to be localized. We have to explicitly localize `var2`.